# Sharing link from mobile browser shows ip instead of domain name

Tags: laravel, share, domain-name

I have a domain, ‘example.com’ and when I share some of its web pages via a mobile browser (only in Safari and chrome app) to social media, the URL is displayed as an IP ex(http://31.08.94.4:99999) instead of my domain name.

I'm working in laravel framework.

For a clear understanding, I updated screenshot below,

This is the screenshot of what happens when I share from my mobile:

http://prnt.sc/nkxfj5

And this is what happens when the proxy IP is shared instead of the actual domain name:

http://prnt.sc/nkxg8f

Comment: check APP_URL in your .env file

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I faced this issue for some of my pages only not for all pages. So I think the issue is not in APP_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an solution for this issue,

canonical url of site is used while sharing the site.

So check your canonical url set in your site using,

```
   document.querySelector('link[rel=canonical]');
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be something on your webserver side. Are you using Apache? In that case check your virtualhost settings to make sure no direct access is even possible and it's set to your domain. For Nginx I'm not sure. Did you also check your DNS settings?

Comment: Redirect URL and reverse proxy setting are working perfect in browser but only when shared through mobile it’s displayed as proxy url instead of proxy name